# function gets called even when the ID is not present in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $("#mySelector").ready(function () {
        window.alert('What the hell!!!');
    });
 });
```

I would expect pop up window to appear every time the `mySelector` appears somewhere in the document.

The problem I am facing right now is this code is running (I get a pop up) even when the selector does not exist in the document.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ready` function is executed when the *DOM* is ready, actually the `ready` event is fired even when you don't pass any arguments to jQuery, ie `$().ready()`, it ignores the selector. You can use `length` property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( $("#mySelector").length ) {
       // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$.ready` is a method of *all* jQuery objects, regardless of whether they contain any elements or not. Here's the relevant part of [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L362).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a valid use of `ready()`. The `.ready()` method fires its handler when the DOM is ready, or if it's already loaded, which it clearly will be. It basically ignores the selector.

---

Typically with jQuery methods you don't need to test for existence. They'll usually fail quietly.

```
 // Does nothing with no matches
$("#mySelector").each(function() {
    alert("foobar!");
});
```

Comment: +1, thank you. Isn't this going to execute for every `mySelector`?

Comment: @GETah: When there's no match, then no, there's no element on which to execute. If your selector finds matches, then it'll execute once for each match. It's pretty rare that you'd actually need to manually test for the existence of an element.